# Largest Prime factor (Project Euler in Rust)

Tags: rust, primes, factors

I've been working on my Rust a bit and want to know how idiomatic my rust code is for the following Project Euler problem:
`What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?`

I'm not looking for ways to improve efficiency or how to improve the strategy, but purely what I can improve with my Rust technique. There's two files: `src/prime/sieve.rs` which has a function for generating a vector of prime numbers, and `src/p003.rs` which is where the problem is solved.

```
// src/prime/sieve.rs

pub fn sieve(ceil: usize) -> Vec<usize> {
    let mut is_prime = vec![true; ceil + 1];
    is_prime[0] = false;
    if ceil >= 1 {
        is_prime[1] = false
    }

    for num in 2..ceil + 1 {
        if is_prime[num] {
            let mut factor = num * num;
            while factor <= ceil {
                is_prime[factor] = false;
                factor += num;
            }
        }
    }

    is_prime
        .iter()
        .enumerate()
        .filter_map(|(p, &is_p)| if is_p { Some(p) } else { None })
        .collect()
}
```

```
// src/prime/mod.rs

pub mod sieve;
```

```
// src/p003.rs

// https://projecteuler.net/problem=3
mod prime;
use prime::sieve::sieve;

fn biggest_prime_factor(n: usize) -> usize {
    for p in sieve((600851475143_f32.sqrt()) as usize).iter().rev() {
        if n % *p == 0 {
            return *p;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", biggest_prime_factor(600851475143));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think

```rust
    for p in sieve((600851475143_f32.sqrt()) as usize).iter().rev() {
```

should be

```rust
    for p in sieve(((n as f32).sqrt()) as usize).iter().rev() {
```

#### Alternative approach

You could chain an iterator in runtime:

```rust
#[test]
fn main_playground() {
    // Sieve iterator-style
    let number: u128 = 600851475143;
    let upper_limit: u128 = (number as f32).sqrt().floor() as _;

    let mut sieve: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = _>> = Box::new(2..=upper_limit);

    while let Some(prime_number) = sieve.next() {
        sieve = Box::new(sieve.filter(move |&x| x % prime_number != 0));
        if number % (prime_number as u128) == 0 {
            dbg!(prime_number);
        }
    }
}
```

The answer is still `6857`. But output is

```
running 1 test
[src\problem_003.rs:12] prime_number = 71  
[src\problem_003.rs:12] prime_number = 839 
[src\problem_003.rs:12] prime_number = 1471
[src\problem_003.rs:12] prime_number = 6857
```

I can think of many more approaches to this. I'd actually build a `Sieve` iterator
if I were you.